# Why is the font color NOT black

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, css

The body text is #444 which is hard on the eyes.  Stackoverflow.com uses black, easy to read.  How about either allowing preferences (hard), or just color the text black (easy) so it is easier to read?

Answer (score 3):

I have darkened the text, please let me know if it's better for you. I didn't use a pure black on white treatment because it's a bit too harsh on the eye in my experience dealing with users. (of course monitors' gamma can vary quite a bit).

Comment: The question titles (on that root and question pages) are so bright a blue that they look fuzzy on my lcd (esp. on the root page). Perhaps a deeper shade of blue would work better, something in-between the current blue and the color used in the site name at the top? Much of the root/questions page below the header looks washed-out and fuzzy as-is.